# In the program I am developing I need to open the webcam using java. for that i have coded using opencv but the following exception popups

Tags: java, opencv, netbeans-8

Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: no opencv_java320 in java.library.path

I even change the path in properties but still the same error occurs please help me get through this

Comment: Did you find a solution? I am having the exact same issue!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After struggling with the exact same issue, I believe I have solved this problem. Place opencv_java320.dll in your Java path. In my case this was in 'C:\Program Files\Java\jre1.8.0_131\bin' (where there are a bunch of other libraries).

You will also need to call `System.loadLibrary(Core.NATIVE_LIBRARY_NAME);` before you make use of any OpenCV classes.

Answer (score 0):

How did you configure your project libraries?  Its seems like you're missing a library configuration.